# Use pyqt4 to create GUI that runs python script

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have written a python script that manipulates data and then saves it into an excel file with the following function:

```
def saveData():
    table = pd.DataFrame(data)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('manipulatedData.xlsx')
    table.to_excel(writer, 'sheet 1')
    writer.save()
```

I also have the following super basic/minimalistic gui window:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
window.setWindowTitle("PyQt Test!")
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonLogoSmall.png'))
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I really would like to know is this:

1) How can I let the user of my gui select the location + name for the manipulatedData file?

2) How can I add a "run" button, that starts my python script and manipulates the data, before it saves the manipulated data to the desired location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyQt4` has `QLineEdit()` and `QPushButton()`

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

# --- functions ---

def my_function(event=None):
    print 'Button clicked: event:', event
    print linetext.text()

    # run your code

# --- main ---

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

# add "layout manager"
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(vbox)

# add place for text
linetext = QtGui.QLineEdit(window)
vbox.addWidget(linetext)

# add button 
button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run", window)
vbox.addWidget(button)

# add function to button 
button.clicked.connect(my_function)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```